# Is it a poke in the eye with a sharp, or blunt stick?

Tags: metaphors, cliche

Is it "better than a poke in the eye with a sharp stick", or "better than a poke in the eye with a blunt stick"?

I suspect that some sort of metaphor testing facility in the Discworld concluded that virtually anything was better than a poke in the eye with a sharp stick, but apart from that I'm not 100% certain.

Side question: is there a term for when a metaphor or cliche gets mutated?

Comment: Note that the [original](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphemus) poke in the eye with a burnt stick was given by Ulysses to the cyclops Polyphemus, blinding him, well before this expression arose in modern English.

Comment: i did not know what any of this means but better than a poke in the eye with a burnt stick might mean and i quote "better than nothing''.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Shorter dictionary of catch phrases* (Rosalind Fergusson, 1994) has the *blunt* version.

[image: book screenshot]

*A dictionary of slang and unconventional English: colloquialisms and catch phrases, fossilised jokes and puns, general nicknames, vulgarisms and such Americanisms as have been naturalised* (E. Partridge and P. Beale, 2002) has both:

[image: book shot]

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've ever heard the expression is *better than a sharp stick in the eye*.  Mileage will doubtless vary.

Comment: Only way I've heard this is "better than getting poked in the eye with a sharp stick." The blunt-stick version cited by Partridge above makes more logical sense, but I've never encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure both blunt and burnt are only recent changes to the original saying that I grew up with back fifties when the saying then was "Burnt" stick. I had never heard blunt or burnt growing up from anyone back then.

Comment: ??? If you never heard blunt or burnt growing up, why was the saying then "Burnt" stick?